# HTML5 link to subpage to a div container

Tags: html, hyperlink, ref

is it possible to ref a subpage direct to a `div`
like `#subpage.div3` or smth ?
If jquery does it also valid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a anchor to your link. So let's say for example you have a navigation something like this:

```
<div class="navigation">
  <a href="/subpage#div3>
</div>
```

Then on your subpage HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="div1">Div 1 content</div>
  <div id="div2">Div 2 content</div>
  <div id="div3">Div 3 content</div>
</div>
```

When navigating to the subpage and having the anchor #div3 in your href on the link, the subpage will be shown where `div3` is.